# Algorithm for multiple extended string matching

Tags: algorithm, text-mining

I need to implement an algorithm for multiple extended string matching in text.

**Extended** means the presence of wildcards (any number of characters instead of a star), for example:

```
abc*def //matches abcdef, abcpppppdef etc.
```

**Multiple** means that the search is going on simultaneously for multiple string patterns (not a separate search for each pattern), for example:

```
abc*def
abc
whatever
some*string
```

**QUESTION:**

What is the fast algorithm that can do multiple extended string matching?

Preferably, optimized for SIMD instructions and multicore implementation. Open source implementation (C/C++/Python) would be great as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it might make sense to start by reading the following  Wikipedia article's section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times. You can then perform a literature review on algorithms, implementing *regular expression pattern matching*.

In terms of practical **implementation**, there is a large variety of *regular expression (regex)* engines in a form of libraries, focused on one or more programming languages. Most likely, the best and most popular option is the C/C++ [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org), with its newest version PCRE2, released in 2015. Another C++ regex library, which is quite popular at Google, is [RE2](https://code.google.com/p/re2). I recommend you to read [this paper](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html), along with the two other, linked within the article, for details on algorithms, implementation and benchmarks. Just recently, Google has released [RE2/J](https://github.com/google/re2j) - a linear time version of RE2 for Java: see [this blog post](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/02/re2j-linear-time-regular-expression.html) for details. Finally, I ran across an interesting pure C regex library [TRE](https://github.com/laurikari/tre), which offers way too many cool features to list here. However, you can read about them all on [this page](http://laurikari.net/tre/about).

**P.S.** If the above is not enough for you, feel free to visit [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) for details of many more regex engines/libraries and their comparison across several criteria. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Aleksandr Blekh, thank you for the great reply! I'm looking for the speed processing of at least 10 Gbps on a single core of a modern CPU. Also, I don't need regular expression processing, just multiple extended string matching. From the paper you mentioned it seems that speeds wasn't bad.

Comment: By the way, do you have any practical experience with any of these engines? What can you recommend from your experience?

Comment: I would like to emphasize my interest in algorithms/implementations that rely heavily on SIMD instructions in modern CPUs.

Comment: @Konstantin, you're very welcome! I'm glad you liked my answer. Frankly, I don't have direct experience with libraries I've referred to, other than reading about them - sorry I can't be of more help in that regard. If I'll have additional thoughts or information, related to your questions and comments, I will certainly let you know. Good luck!